# Three.js - Model not showing after importing into the scene

Tags: three.js

So I made a simple blender model and wanted to import it into my scene.

Here is a part of code that could be troubling:

```js
// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader() //must be added before
//dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('/draco/')

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader)



gltfLoader.load('/models/hamburger.glb', (gltf) => {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);

})


//Objects

const floor = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50),
    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0x444444,
        metalness: 0,
        roughness: 0.5
    })
)

floor.receiveShadow = true
floor.rotation.x = -  Math.PI * 0.5 
scene.add(floor)

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.8)
scene.add(ambientLight)

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6)
directionalLight.castShadow = true
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.set(1024, 1024)
directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 7
directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 7
directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 7
directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - 7
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 15
directionalLight.position.set(5, 5, 5)
scene.add(directionalLight)

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.z = 2
camera.position.x = 2
camera.position.y = 2
```

However when I try to import it, it's not showing even though I get no errors and everyting else works.

Comment: There can be a couple of issues. E.g. sometimes user add no lights to their scenes or the camera setting are inappropriate. Please share your entire code and the glTF asset in this thread.

Comment: I've just edited the code.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the glTF asset?

Comment: I actually "fixed" the problem by exporting the model as .obj (Wavefront), then importing it and exporting it again as a glTF and it worked in the scene.